# Video loading but not playing rails 6 video_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video

I'm trying to play a video in the header of a site.  I added the video to the assets folder and using the code below, the video will load but when I press the play button, the controls shows the counter counting but there is nothing playing.  I can even download the video and it will play. Autoplay is also not working.  Here is my code for the video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="../../../assets/Denver-judo-practice-1080.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Video tag is not supported in this browser.
</video>
```

I also tried the following codw with the same result.

```
<%= video_tag "Denver-judo-practice-1080.mp4", width: "80%", controls: :controls, autoplay: :autoplay, loop: :loop %>
```

What I'm ultimately looking for is a vdieo that plays when loaded but pauses when the user scrolls down but my first issue is the get it to play at all.

Comment: I think chrome does not allow autoplay. for that, you have to make it "muted"

Go through this link :  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Muting it did make the auto play work, thanks but the bigger proglem is that the video is playing but it's blank.  If I click to download it, the downloaded video plays just fine but in the browser the counter is going but nothing appears on the screen.